# Facebook Can't scrape my Joomla website even when i added OG:tags

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-opengraph

I have all the OG tags specified but Facebook still can't read my website. What's wrong?

Here is my HEAD section

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
  <base href="http://www.mojadebica.pl/kryminalne/1392-akcja-trzezwy-poranek-na-podkarpaciu" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Dębica, pizzerie, pizza, wyszukiwarka, jedzenie, na, wynos, dyżury, aptek, noclegi, reklama, strony www, portal, informacje, ogłoszenia, repertuar kin, oferty, pracy, forum, org, nasza" />
  <meta name="og:image" content="http://www.mojadebica.pl/images/thumbs/poranek.jpg" />
  <meta name="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta name="title" content="Akcja 'Trzeźwy poranek' na Podkarpaciu" />
  <meta name="og:title" content="Portal MojaDebica.pl" />
  <meta name="og:url" content="http://www.mojadebica.pl/kryminalne/1392-akcja-trzezwy-poranek-na-podkarpaciu" />
  <meta name="og:site_name" content="E-max" />
  <meta name="og:description" content="Moja Dębica - najnowsze informacje i aktualności z Dębicy. Największa baza ofert pracy, ogłoszenia z dębicy i okolic oraz wyszukiwarka pizzy!" />
  <meta name="description" content="Moja Dębica - najnowsze informacje i aktualności z Dębicy. Największa baza ofert pracy, ogłoszenia z dębicy i okolic oraz wyszukiwarka pizzy!" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! 1.5 - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Akcja &quot;Trzeźwy poranek&quot; na Podkarpaciu</title>
  <link href="/templates/back-to-nature/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/system/css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/com_k2/css/k2.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/com_jcomments/tpl/default/style.css?v=12" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/mootools.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/modal.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_k2/js/k2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_jcomments/js/jcomments-v2.1.js?v=7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_jcomments/libraries/joomlatune/ajax.js?v=3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/caption.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

        window.addEvent('domready', function() {

            SqueezeBox.initialize({});

            $$('a.modal').each(function(el) {
                el.addEvent('click', function(e) {
                    new Event(e).stop();
                    SqueezeBox.fromElement(el);
                });
            });
        });
var K2SitePath = '/';
  </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/mdnew/stylemd4.4.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/templates/mdnew/favicon.ico" />    

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link href="/templates/back-to-nature/css/ieonly.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-15391002-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>   

</head>
```

And here is sample article:

http://www.mojadebica.pl/video/1388-sonda-gdzie-jest-najlepsze-jedzenie-w-debicy-video-hd

Missing Required Property:  The 'og:url' property is required, but not present.

but it's specified here:

```
<meta name="og:url" content="http://www.mojadebica.pl/kryminalne/1392-akcja-trzezwy-poranek-na-podkarpaciu" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your webserver configuration.

In your response headers, your server is sending `Content-Encoding: none`. This [is not valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mojadebica.pl%2Fvideo%2F1388-sonda-gdzie-jest-najlepsze-jedzenie-w-debicy-video-hd&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

There may be additional rules in there that are sending [the Facebook parser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mojadebica.pl%2Fvideo%2F1388-sonda-gdzie-jest-najlepsze-jedzenie-w-debicy-video-hd) a `403: Forbidden` reply.

If you host with an ISP, contact them about this problem. If you're rolling your own server, you'll need to dig into the LiteSpeed documentation.

Comment: I had some Malware injected in my Joomla. Is that possible, that error ocurrs because of that malware? How can i check it?

Comment: Your site didn't give me any warnings, and I've got all my malware checking safeguards set to high. If you're talking about a compromised Joomla component, you need to wipe your site and DB clean and do a fresh install. For troubleshooting, I visit the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), the[W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) and the [URIBL Database](https://admin.uribl.com/) in order to check a site that won't parse.